# not able to create controller from console : cakephp : showing fatal error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to create a controller in cakephp(1.3) using console. I am using windows XP and XAMPP.

My current cake console settings below

C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>cake

> ♀ Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.4 Console
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- Current Paths:  -app: console 
>   -working: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console
>   -root: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake 
>   -core: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog
>
> Changing Paths: your working path
>   should be the same as your application
>   path to change your path use the
>   '-app' param. Example: -app
>   relative/path/to/myapp or -app
>   /absolute/path/to/myapp
>
> Available Shells:  acl [CORE]
>   i18n [CORE]
>
> api [CORE]
>   schema [CORE]
>
> bake [CORE]
>   testsuite [CORE]
>
> console [CORE]
>
> To run a command, type 'cake
>   shell_name [args]' To get help on a
>   specific command, type 'cake
>   shell_name help'
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>-app
>   c:\xampp '-app' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>

what are the path settings I need to set for creating a controller from console ?
I tried to change the app path but, when I type command **cake**  It goes app directory to console,

Could you please help me to solve this issue

when I try to create a controller I am getting the following error :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>cake bake controller news

♀
Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.4 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : console
Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console
---------------------------------------------------------------

Creating file C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console\controllers\news_cont
roller.php
Wrote `C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console\controllers\news_controller.
php`

You can download SimpleTest from http://simpletest.org
Bake is detecting possible fixtures..

Warning: include_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console\config\databa
se.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cak
e\apressblog\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on line 23

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\co
nsole\config\database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C
:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on line 23


Fatal error: ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source default
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on li
ne 102


C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>
```

Comment: Did you bake the model first?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your [database.php](http://book.cakephp.org/view/922/Database-Configuration) file in the config folder so that Cake knows what database to connect to for the models.

Once you have done this you need to create your database schema and then bake the model for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd been having the same problem and was googling when I stumbled upon this. I was getting the same 'Warning: include_once...' error as you did.

I figured out this was happening only when I ran the 'cake bake' command from the ..\cake\console\ folder like you did.

So here's what fixed this issue for me. I added path to the console folder to my environment variables. Now I could call the cake bake command from anywhere.

Then I changed directory to your app folder e.g. ...\htdocs\myCakeWebsite\app

Then run 'cake bake' command! It worked fine from then on.

sources: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvJH0wTlRg